# HTML redirect code timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I made this code some time ago for random events on my website. The code works great, but I wanted to add a timer.

What I want it so when the user refreshes/enters page, you are redirected, then, I want it to redirect again to the same page every X amount of seconds.

```
<script>
var test = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1) <= 1;

if (test) {
window.location = "URL";
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html

Comment: @frong,If you want redirecting when the page first loads,Remove 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without Timer:**

If you want redirect user,can use this line in script:

```
window.location = "URL";
```

When user enter in site or refreshs it,get redirect.

**With Timer:**

*A)One time*

**Note**:You can use `setTimeout` too.

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
    window.location = "URL"     
},3000);
```

*B)infinite*

```
setInterval(function(){
    window.location = "URL"     
},3000);
```

Comment: @frong,If you want redirecting when the page first loads,Remove `3000`.

Comment: yes, but what about the 5 second redirect after that?

Comment: when user enter in site,`script` get run.what is need ,repeat after `5s`?

Comment: this script needs to be in the page that you redirect to. Once a visitor leaves your site you can not redirect them any more.

Comment: Ok,so why you use `timer`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var seconds = 5

setTimeout(() => {
   window.location = "URL";
}, seconds * 1000)
```

Since you're reloading the page you don't need a repeating interval. This timer will be started each time the page is redirected.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one thing, it isn't redirecting when the page first loads, it does after 5 seconds. Is there any way to fix that? I want it to redirect instantly, then go to the 5 second interval.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `meta refresh` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.google.com/" />
```

Note that use of meta refresh is deprecated. You may visit this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) for more information.